# Add a "ripple" effect on click example in W3schools

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am studying Css recently in w3schools and I can't completely figure out how does this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate2) work.

I don't konw what's the difference or usage of the following 3 transition codes in this example

```
.button:after {
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
   }

.button:after {
transition: all 0.8s;
  }

.button:active:after {
transition: 0s
}
```

It would be greatful if someone can help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better learn from [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
```

in your case

```
.button:after {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
 }
```

here you will need to add

```
transition-property: font-size;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-delay: 2s;/*if you want a delay*/
```

**all** means apply to all properties of the element

```
   .button:after {
      transition: all 0.8s;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button:active:after {
transition: 0s
}
```

This makes the white box visible on click within 0 seconds.

```
.button:after {
transition: all 0.8s;
  }
```

This makes the white box invisible after 0.8 seconds.

```
.button:after {
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
   }
```

This doesn't serve any real purpose in your given example, but could be used in combination with (for example) a `:hover` effect.